What is the appropriate torque for an IRD setback seatpost and what could be done to prevent it from slipping?
The system is a single-bolt, M8 size. Generic Park Tool advice would suggest 20-24 Nm---does anyone have more specific suggestions/experience? 

Where I am, I am unable to get a better seatpost with large setback and I do not want to replace either the bike or the Brooks saddle.

20-24 Nm sounds about right for a seatpost head with a single M8 bolt. As for preventing it from slipping, some carbon paste (a gritty paste intended to help prevent carbon fiber components from slipping at reduced torque values) may help by increasing friction between all the components. Properly tightening the bolt should hold everything together though, with the paste only acting as a backup.
